# strong convergence in $W^{1,p}$ if $L^p$ convergence of function and all derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\{u_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for $p \in (1, \infty)$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ open, bounded.

If $u_n  \to u^* \in L^p(\Omega)$ and $\nabla u_n \to 0 \in L^p(\Omega)$. Is it true that $u^* \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $\nabla u^* = 0$?

If the answer is yes, why does this hold? In particular, why does $u^*$ need to be weakly differentiable and why is the weak derivative given by the limit of $\nabla u_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\nabla u^*$ exists in a weak sense and is equal to $0$ then $\nabla u^*\in L^p$ and so $u^*\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. So it suffices to prove that
$$\int_{\Omega}u^*\partial_i\varphi=0\qquad \forall \varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega) $$
We know that
$$ \int_{\Omega}u_n\partial_i\varphi=-\int_{\Omega}\varphi\partial_iu_n$$
so it suffices to show the following convergences (can you?)
$$\int_{\Omega}u_n\partial_i\varphi \to \int_{\Omega}u^*\partial_i\varphi,\qquad \int_{\Omega}\varphi \partial_iu_n\to 0 $$
and then the thesis follows.

Comment: Since $\partial_i \varphi$ induces a linear functional on $L^p$, and we have $u_n \longrightarrow u^*$ in strong, and hence also in the weak sense?

Comment: That's okay, I think. More precisely for your argument to work you need that $\partial_i\varphi$ induces a *continuous* linear functional on $L^p$, and to prove that you need Hölder's inequality, which you can apply since $\partial_i\varphi\in L^{p'}$. But here you can immediately apply the same inequality to obtain the convergence without additional arguments.